# What's the ancient folder in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes, peers

I'm new to the nodes world and i'm trying to setup my own with Geth on Windows. I was wondering what the /ancient folder does for the Node. Please correct if i'm wrong, but synthetically this is what the other folders should do:

**/keystore** should contain my wallet keys, if i have setup one.

**/geth** should contain the Node itself,the blockchain data such as blocks and the cache.

So, what the **/ancient** folder is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's folder to save part of your blockchain - ancient database for ancient serments(contains away past blocks and receipts). By default it has created in geth/chaindata but you can transfer it in another place using parameter in command line.
It is used by reorg chain or redownloading. The use of this database is called "freezer". You can read about it more. It is started to use from geth 1.9.0.

Comment: Thanks @foreston. Do you have any papers where can i read about it?

Comment: See this is https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/ . It is basic release notes about freezer once this separate db was became.